# is Queue.full() dependable when using a single thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

Python's [thread-safe `Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) object has a useful function named [`Queue.full()`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.full) with the following documentation:

> Return True if the queue is full, False otherwise. If full() returns
>   True it doesn’t guarantee that a subsequent call to get() will not
>   block. Similarly, if full() returns False it doesn’t guarantee that a
>   subsequent call to put() will not block.

It's obvious that in a multi-threaded scenario where multiple threads `put()` items in the queue and multiple threads `get()` items, there are race conditions. However if only one single thread uses `put()`, and one single different thread uses `get()` can't the value of `full()` be trusted?
Is this a Python implementation specific question? If so, what is the answer for CPython?

Comment: You are talking about one consumer thread and one producer thread (in sum 2), right?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean that you are only using one thread to do everything, then yes. If nothing else is accessing it, there is no way that it can change.

If you mean two threads overall, then no, there are still opportunities for race conditions.

Either way, the real question is why do you want to do it like this? Try it, catch the exception if it fails - that's the Python way.

```
try:
    some_queue.get_nowait()
except queue.Empty:
    do_something_else()
```

This has the advantage of being thread-safe in the future, and avoids the race condition under any circumstance (threads are not needed to cause it, you could just make a call that changes the code in between the check and the get by accident).

Edit: As [larsmans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166749/larsmans) pointed out in the comment below, among the other issues to do with race conditions, CPython has `Queue.full()` marked as *likely to be removed at some point*, so there is another reason to avoid it.

Comment: No, it is not. Scenario: A (put) and B (get) are threads. Queue q is full. A calls q.full() which is returning True, B gets an item, A is expecting q to be full but it is not...

Comment: motivation for not using try\except: `except` has an efficiency penalty in python, and in cases where you expect many such cases (maybe 50% of cases) it _might_ be more efficient to use the `full()` function to check before using `put()`. benchmarking is advisable

Comment: @Jonathan The readability and potential race condition means that unless this is a hugely performance critical bit of code, you should use exceptions. It's accepted Python style to ask for forgiveness, not permission.

Comment: @ms4py He says 'using a single thread' - I take that to mean one thread overall. I agree later on he is a bit less clear, but I think he is talking about the same single thread.

Comment: Well, he could use the `deque` directly without synchronization if there is only one thread, so the question would not make any sense.

Comment: @ms4py Edited my answer to address either potential option.

Comment: OK, agreed with this explanation. :-)

Comment: To re-raise a point from my now deleted answer: not only is `full` not safe, but in the latest hg version of CPython it's also marked "likely to be removed at some point". +1.

Comment: What I meant in the question was one thread that `put`s and another thread that `get`s. Together two threads. I'm asking if the put thread sees that the queue is _not_ full, then it must really be not full as no other thread puts. Symmetrically, if the get thread sees the queue is full then it must really be full as no other thread may get. That is exactly what I wanted to find out. Even if using the queue in this way is not common, it is still an interesting technical question, that just happens to make a difference in my case.

Comment: anyway, I indeed implemented something similar to what @Lattyware suggested, but only on the `put` side... the `get` side in my case blocks and with good reason

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, your scenarios *might* be without a race condition but definitely not the other way round: The `put` thread can't get reliable if the queue is full and the `get` thread can't be sure that the queue is not full.

Answer (score 0):

I once observed a delayed update of the isfull-information in the Queue() because it was using a special thread by itself(!) to do things like put and get. So I would not rely on this even if I(!) am using just one thread. Maybe Queue isn't.

Comment: This is not true in the CPython implementation: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/queue.py

Comment: It isn't in my current implementation as well, but I've seen it once (or remember incorrectly) and the spec only states that one should *not* rely on it being predictable.  So unless one knows all implementations of Queue this shall run on, I'd not assume anything.  And there *are* better alternatives like catching the exeption as posted in the other answer.